# Why doesn't the post request return back any data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get my results from my college's website with python, I typed this script:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make a request to the website
url = 'http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp'
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the response and create a BeautifulSoup object 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 

# Find the input field we need to fill with our ID 
input_field = soup.find('input', {'name': 'x_st_settingno', 'id': 'x_st_settingno'}) 
input_field['value'] = 8936 # Fill in our ID 

  
# Find the submit button and click it 
submit_button = soup.find('input', {'name': 'Submit', 'id': 'Submit'}) 
data = {input_field['name']: input_field['value'], submit_button['name']: submit_button['value']}
response2 = requests.post(url, data=data) 

 # Parse the response and create a BeautifulSoup object  
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'html.parser')  

print(`soup.find('form:nth-of-type(2) table tbody tr:first-of-type td b font')`)
```

But it always returns `None`. I do not know why?

The `print(soup.find('form:nth-of-type(2) table tbody tr:first-of-type td b font'))` part is just the head of the table that contains the link to my results, If I looked for the link it returns `None` as well.

What am I doing wrong, I am not good with web scraping I just started learning, I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: Hi there. First, the backtick in your very final print statement looks weird. Have you tried without it? I'm talking about the ` symbol. (Unless you're using Python 2 instead of Python 3 )

Comment: Next up, in the code you share, you only have a single check, at the very end. The error could be in any of the steps before. I'd go step by step and print out variables along the way. For example, what does `response.text` look like? What does `response2.text` look like?

Comment: Yes, The first response returns the status of the request which is 200, the first soup is the html of the page. the second request is also successful, the second soup is like the first soup, So I really do not know what to do

Comment: I think that there's a problem where I try to locate the place I would fill my ID in or with the clicking of the submit button, All of these stuff I cannot check for, That's why I asked here.

Comment: I can't view the website in my browser for some reason. It's possible that the button isn't actually sending a straightforward post request but rather doing some javascript stuff...

Comment: @EsmaelMaher check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        params = {
            "Submit": "%C8%CD%CB",
            "x_dep": "",
            "x_gro": "",
            "x_sec": "",
            "x_st_name": "",
            "x_st_settingno": "8936",
            "z_dep": "=",
            "z_gro": "=",
            "z_sec": "LIKE",
            "z_st_name": "LIKE",
            "z_st_settingno": "="
        }
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        res = urljoin(url, soup.select_one('.ewTableRow span.aspmaker a')[
            'href'])
        r = req.get(res)

        df = pd.read_html(r.content)
        print(df)


main('http://app1.helwan.edu.eg/Commerce/HasasnUpMlist.asp')
```

Comment: I don't know why my friend but, after a long headache I figured it out yesterday and produced the exact same piece of code you just suggested. but thank you so much for your time.